# Floating left css

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm new there. I'm studying web design, in particular css.
Now I have a question, I need to pose in same place to div, one contain menu and other image with text like that.

I need to position side-info behind side menu

```css
#sidemenu {
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
}

#sidemenu ul {
  line-height: 50px;
}

#sidemenu ul li {
  border-bottom: solid 1px black;
}

.side-info {
  width: 650px;
  padding-left: 50px;
}

.side-info img {
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidemenu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Brand Creation</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Graphic Design</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Web Design &amp; development</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Packing Design</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="side-info"> <img src="images/template5_12.jpg" alt="computer">
  <p class="com">Web Site &amp; Apps</p>
  <h2>Meddison Architecture</h2>
  <p class="par">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque ultrices quam at orci aliquet, sollicitudin iaculis felis vehicula. Proin id nisl nec nisl feugiat egestas at eu odio</p>
  <p class="linkto">View Project</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You can edit your post to contain the code you put in comments. Also add some context, please. You definitely don't need to include the path to your CSS document, but you do need to include your code. Edit your post to contain it, not the comments.

Comment: You should update  your question not add code in comment ..  you can also format the code in question using brackets button above the question text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
ul, li {margin:0;}

#wrapper {width:1000px;}

#sidemenu {
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
}

#sidemenu ul li{
   padding-top: 10px; 
  padding-bottom:10px;
}

#sidemenu ul li {
  border-bottom: solid 1px black;
}

.side-info {
  width: 650px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  float:right;
}

.side-info img {
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="sidemenu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Brand Creation</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Graphic Design</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Web Design &amp; development</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Packing Design</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="side-info"> <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/140x100" alt="computer">
  <p class="com">Web Site &amp; Apps</p>
  <h2>Meddison Architecture</h2>
  <p class="par">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque ultrices quam at orci aliquet, sollicitudin iaculis felis vehicula. Proin id nisl nec nisl feugiat egestas at eu odio</p>
  <p class="linkto">View Project</p>
</div>
  </div>
```

Dany, I would recommend you to start with [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/getting-started/introduction/) one of the most popular front-end frameworks. It has all the necessary CSS for your requirements and it is easy though. Based on my understanding from your question you can achieve with zero custom CSS.

Comment: can you help me?

Comment: Understood @Paulie_D modified the answer message. Thank You